# DC Motor Charging

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I've got a 12v, 8w Dc motor. Can I power it up with 12v,1amp AC-DC charger?

Can I use 12v charger with any Amp charger?

Note: It works fine with 6x1.5v AA batteries.

Comment: charging a motor?

Comment: You should be able to power it with that (though it may struggle a little bit to start), but I'm not sure "charge" is the word you want.

Comment: Maybe. Its rated current is 2/3A. But it'll take several times that current when starting. Does your charger shut down under momentary overcurrent?

Comment: Haven't tried the charger yet

Comment: See also https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/34745/2028

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A motor takes about 10x normal current on startup depending on DCR resistance with an ohm-meter. So a motor at rated load of 8W/12V= 2/3A thus for starting x10 or ~ 6.6A so a 1A charger will start with 15% of rated starting torque.

### Other info

The most power is the combination battery + charger just like a car but your charger might overheat if not designed for this load.

A Battery cell is equivalent to a minimum chemical cell voltage with an UltraCap of 10kF order of magnitude and ESR in series.  The ESR (Effective Series R) rises exponentially below 5~10% SoC.(State of Charge)

A Battery Charger is somewhat the opposite. It is a high impedance Constant Current (CC) up to about 85~90% SoC for the battery as it charges up to the terminal CV constant charge Voltage where the charger is now low impedance but the battery current drops until 5~10% of CC = cutoff threshold is reached.

Depending on how smart the charger is at detecting the battery **initial and final conditions** may/may not behave as you wish for a motor drive.

Since a motor force/load determines the acceleration rate, you can expect this to give a controlled rate. We expect you mean an automotive 12V motor that might tolerate 14.2V and not a motor rated for less voltage due to heat rise.

So your performance will be slower for starting but faster for final RPM/V if the charger goes to 14.2V vs a 12V regulated supply.

**Without inductive kickback protection, beware that an abrupt turn off of motor might damage the charger with overvoltage.**  Thus it is not wise to do what you suggest.

Yet including a suitable 12V battery string with the correct voltage rating connected to the charger will reduce the risk and improve the power source.